# Drupal 7 contextual filter and exposed filter in calendar views

Tags: drupal-7, calendar, drupal-exposed-filter, drupal-contextual-filters

I've created a calendar views wherein i can see all the events I've created. I also add contextual filter(start_date_of_event) to set the date to current on the first load of the page. It is working fine but my problem is that when i put an exposed filter(start_date_of_event) same field i use in my contextual filter, and tried to run it ? it seems it wont work.

To further explain. **Below are the sample link**:

```
1. with contextual filter (working) : http://test.com/test-calendar-listing/2014-12
2. with contextual filter and exposed filter (not working) :http://test.com/test-calendar-listing/2014-12?field_state_country_value=All&field_sample_method_of_delivery_tid=All&field_topics_tid=All&field_provider_type_value=All&field_event_status_value=1&field_start_date_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Bmonth%5D=11&field_start_date_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Byear%5D=2014
```

What i did so far is used filter harmonizer but no luck.I also tried to used hook_form_alter to redirect the page the link i want but not working also. can you please suggest what is the best thing to do? or what are things i am missing ? thanks for your help.